# Getting randomly empty request using Ajax in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, apache

After an upgrade from `PHP 5.5.9` version to `5.6` when I submit a form data (or ajax) using post method I have an empty request value and I get an errors in the controller because of the unexpected empty request.
It's not happening all the time (and not in all the forms), if I send the same data sometimes its working and I receive the data and sometimes I don't get it.

The php.ini is including:

```
post_max_size = 200M
max_input_vars = 1000
max_execution_time = 30
```

We tried to use `dd(request()))` and its null, upgrade to `PHP 7.3`, upgrade the laravel version to `5.8.29` and it still likes that.

i also have errors logger in the db so i can see all the errors with they original requests, most of the logs have exists requests value, but few of them have empty request array randomly.

The request to the server is sending by simple ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: POST,
    url: '/my/url/',
    data: {...},
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Did you hear about this issue? Do you have any idea what can we do please?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: i think you might have an error in your `middlewares` that empties of doesn't propagate the request. You know, in the `handle()` method of the middlewares, it's supposed to return `return $next($request)`

Comment: Are your requests going through any form of authentication?. There's a difference between **request** and **response**. What you are checking with `dd(request())` is the request sent from ajax to the server. What you are expecting to receive after ajax call is the returned response. Which of them is not being consistent? Is it both? Have you tried including `error()` method in your ajax call settings to get the nature of the request failure?

Comment: Our request containing all of the form data, but the server side return empty request, as i said, we cant validate this problem every time, but when its happen we can see the correct form data with empty request at the server side, very weird situation.

I changed the content of the RouteServiceMiddleware, it may cause the problem, but we will know if the problem is happen again only in production, till that i searching for any solution that can help solve this issue.

thanks for your help.